# como meter el resultado de una variable en el metodo newton raphson

Tags: python, bucles, typeerror

1.Encontré un código del método de newton raphson, el caso es que quiero que itere el resultado de una ecuaicón guardada en una variable llamada EcuacionCe y su derivada, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, llevo como un mes aprendiendo python y quise implementar su uso para un cálculo de flechas y tensiones.

```
Area =198.26                          #mm^2
Diametro=18.5                         #mm
Peso_por_longitud=0.687               #kg/m
Peso_especifico =0.003465             #kg/m/mm^2
Modulo_de_elasticidad_inicial=5900    #kg/mm^2
Modulo_de_elasticidad_final=7700      #kg/mm^2
Coeficiente_de_dilatacion=0.00001899  #1/ºC
Carga_a_la_ruptura=6373               #kg
Tension_al_17_porciento= 0.1757*Carga_a_la_ruptura #kg
Claro=380                             #m
Coeficiente_de_sobrecarga_m= 1
Temperatura_final=-10
Temperatura_inicial=50
Tension_inicial= Tension_al_17_porciento/Area

  
#Determinación de K1 y K2
K1= Modulo_de_elasticidad_final*Peso_especifico**2/24
K2=Modulo_de_elasticidad_final*Coeficiente_de_dilatacion
print('K1:',K1,'K2:',K2 )

import sympy
from sympy import *

Ecuación de cambio de estado
T2, T1, k1, k2, d, m1, m2, temp2, temp1  = symbols('T2 T1 k1 k2 d m1 m2 temp2 temp1')

(T2**2*(T2+(k1**2*d**2*m1**2/T1**2))+k2*(temp2-temp1)-T1-(k1*m2**2*d**2))

T1=Tension_inicial
d=Claro
m1= 1
temp2=Temperatura_final
temp1=Temperatura_inicial
m2=1.57

EcuacionCE=(T2**2*((T2+(K1*d**2*m1**2/T1**2))+K2*(temp2-temp1)-T1)-(K1*m2**2*d**2))
EcuacionCE

EcuacionCE=expand(EcuacionCE)
EcuacionCE

EcuacionCE
print(EcuacionCE)

#Metodo Newton Raphson
Derivada=(diff(EcuacionCE))
print(Derivada)

import numpy as np

# INGRESO
fT2  = lambda T2: EcuacionCE

dfT2 = lambda T2: Derivada

T20 = 2
tolera = 0.001

# PROCEDIMIENTO
tabla = []
tramo = abs(2*tolera)
T2i = T20
while (tramo>=tolera):
    T2nuevo = T2i - fT2(T2i)/dfT2(T2i)
    tramo  = abs(T2nuevo-T2i)
    tabla.append([T2i,T2nuevo,tramo])
    T2i = T2nuevo

# convierte la lista a un arreglo.
tabla = np.array(tabla)
n = len(tabla)

# SALIDA
print(['T2i', 'T2nuevo', 'tramo'])
np.set_printoptions(precision = 4)
print(tabla)
print('raiz en: ', T2i)
print('con error de: ',tramo)
```

2.El error que me aparece es este, lo que quiero es que donde se introducen las ecuaciones, queden las variables EcuacionCe y Derivada, en si el codigo si meto las ecuaciones solas si funciona.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/fy/f2mwvz7j5zsc8_jfqbyfx17m0000gn/T/ipykernel_777/3737715379.py in <module>
     13 tramo = abs(2*tolera)
     14 T2i = T20
---> 15 while (tramo>=tolera):
     16     T2nuevo = T2i - fT2(T2i)/dfT2(T2i)
     17     tramo  = abs(T2nuevo-T2i)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/core/relational.py in __bool__(self)
    509 
    510     def __bool__(self):
--> 511         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    512 
    513     def _eval_as_set(self):

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Comment: El código que muestras tiene errores de sintaxis y no ejecuta. Lo mejor es que reduzcan el código a lo mínimo necesario para mostrar el problema. Así será posible analizarlo.

Comment: Proporciona un ejemplo mínimo verificable. Es decir, que los demás podamos copiar y ejecutar y que aparezca el error que indicas. El código que suministras no se puede probar

Comment: una disculpa, el codigo de newthon raphson lo saque de aqui  
 http://blog.espol.edu.ec/analisisnumerico/newton-raphson-ejemplo01/. solo cambie x por T2i ya que era el nombre de la variable que implementé en el calculo

Comment: ufff para empezar, es bastante complejo leer tu código, y cuesta entenderlo. habría que aclarar cual es tu variariable (es T2? ) que sucede con el resto de los parámetros? si tienen valores dados, creo que te convendría reducir la función cargando los datos y constantes sin usar simbólico para todo eso.

Comment: use simbólicos para corroborar que la ejecución de la formula estuviera bien y me arrojara una ecuación de la forma x3^ – Px^2 – Q, y de ahi saber el resultado de T2, por eso es la unica variable que no esta asignada